# Put PHP opening and closing tags into variable

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to make my PHP code write another PHP file and need the opening `<?php` and closing `?>` tags included when writing the file.  How would I go about doing that?

Example:

```
$Data = '<?php $keywords = "Testing"; ?>';
```

Full file writing code, which does not work:

```
<?php
$File = "hello.php"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
$Data = '<?php $keywords = "Testing"; ?>';
fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
print "Data Written"; 
fclose($Handle); 
?>
```

Comment: Did you try that? What happens?

Comment: It doesn't seem to write the file, but if I do something like `$Data = '$keywords = "Testing";';` it does.

Comment: Tested here on PHP 5.4.21 - your code works fine. Make sure you have permissions to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample. You are on the right path

```
$string = '<?php 

$dbhost = "'. $_POST["dbhost"]. '";

$dbuname = "'. $_POST["dbuname"]. '";

$dbpass = "'. $_POST["dbpass"]. '";

$dbname = "'. $_POST["dbname"]. '";

$prefix = "'. $_POST["prefix"]. '";

$user_prefix = "'. $_POST["user_prefix"]. '";

$dbtype = "'. $_POST["dbtype"]. '";

?>';



$fp = fopen("config.php", "w");

fwrite($fp, $string);

fclose($fp);
```